# How to make an output log file of the zip file you just extracted

Tags: perl

I have a program that will extract a zip file called "output.zip" and make a directory for it. I would like to make a log file if a certain word is in any of the files I extracted in this case the word is Error. The error I'm getting is saying that the file doesn't exist. How can I fix this?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

 use strict;
 use warnings;

 use Archive::Zip qw(:ERROR_CODES :CONSTANTS);

 my $sSource = "/home/glork/output.zip";
 my $sDest = "/home/glork/zipped";



x_unzip($sSource,$sDest);

sub x_unzip {
my ($zip_file, $out_file, $filter) = @_;
my $zip = Archive::Zip->new($zip_file);
unless ($zip->extractTree($filter || '', $out_file) == AZ_OK) {
    warn "unzip not successful: $!\n";
  }
 }


open(LOGFILE, "/home/glork/zipped/var/log/*.log") or die "can't find file";

while(<LOGFILE>) {
    print "Error in line $.\n" if(/ERROR/);
}
close LOGFILE;
```

Comment: @toolic Yeah I know the file names but, it's a group of files

Comment: You will have to open each file one after another. You cannot write to a bunch of files at the same time. But you can have an array of lexical filehandles, and iterate over it to write to all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. You extract all the files, save the names. Then go through each file looking for errors:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Archive::Zip qw(:ERROR_CODES :CONSTANTS);

my $sSource = "/home/glork/output.zip";
my $sDest = "/home/glork/zipped";

my @extractedFiles;
my $zip = Archive::Zip->new($sSource);
foreach my $member ($zip->members) {
    next if $member->isDirectory;
    (my $extractName = $member->fileName) =~ s{.*/}{};
    $member->extractToFileNamed($sDest.'/'.$extractName);
    push @extractedFiles, $extractName;
    print "Extracted $sDest/$extractName\n";
}

foreach my $logFile (@extractedFiles) {
    open(LOGFILE, "$sDest/$logFile") or die "can't find file";
    while(<LOGFILE>) {
        print "Error in line $.\n" if(/ERROR/);
    }
    close LOGFILE;
}
```

Comment: Cool this works but, is there way for me to put the results in a separate file

Comment: Just open a file for wrting and print errors into that file.